# How to add string to vector of string in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, addition

I have:

```
vector<string> *history;
history = new vector<string>[300];
```

where history should contain several strings (up to 300).

Then I do in order to add a string:

```
std::stringstream sstm;
sstm << frameProc << " ";
string result = sstm.str();
history[xyz]= result;  //This line does not work
```

But that does not work. How should I do this?

Comment: This doesn't work because `result` is a `string`, but `history` is an array of `vector`.

Comment: @Manu343726:  Seems to me that OP doesn't want a `vector <vector>` at all.  They want a single collection of (up to) 300 `string`s.  They are doing the totally wrong thing here.  (Rant about not reading the docs elided)

Answer (score 7):

You are dynamically allocating an array of `vector<string>` here:

```
vector<string> *history;
history = new vector<string>[300];
```

What you really need is a vector of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> history;
std::stringstream sstm;
sstm << frameProc << " ";
std::string result = sstm.str();
history.push_back(result);
```

Comment: But I want to have each string as one complete string. Should I change it to history.push_back(result); then?

Comment: @user3236180 Sorry, I meant `push_back(result)` (or `push_back(sstm.str())`.)

Answer (score 4):

If to answer your question

> How to add string to vector of string in C++

then it is done the following way

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

v.push_back( "Some string" );
```

or

```
v.insert( v.end(), "Some string" );
```

If to consider your code snippet then the correct statement will look

```
history[xyz].push_back( result );
```

or

```
history[xyz].insert( history[xyz].end(), result );
```

**EDIT:**

Also I thought that maybe you are doing something wrong do not understanding what you are doing. Then consider the following code. Maybe it will be helpfull.

```
std::vector<std::string> history( 300 );
//...
history[xyz] += result;
```